# Ajax call to render js in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Here is my log::

```
Started GET "/emain" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-27 22:36:11 +0530
Processing by EmployeeController#emain as HTML
Emp Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "emps".* FROM "emps" WHERE "emps"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "
emps"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered employee/_emp.js.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered employee/_form.html.erb (9.0ms)
Rendered employee/_content.html.erb (14.0ms)
Rendered employee/emain.html.erb within layouts/application (22.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 53.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-27 22:36:11 +0530
```

In `_form.html.erb` i have include the partial

```
<%= render(:partial => "emp.js") %>
```

In `_emp.js.erb`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>...
</script>
```

**On reloading the `/emain` it works perfectly but the error is: when this(below) function (`in coffeescript`) is called it shows the load given above but `js` is not working**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".click").mouseenter ->
    $(".content-wrapper").load "emain #eform"
   return
return
```

Comment: Could you show your html code as well? Please explain 'js is not working'! What are you expecting the js to do?

Comment: here is my fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/sneh_pandya/q42XR/`